# How to use same layout for Android and iPhone using Titanium?

Tags: iphone, android, titanium

I am developing an App using Titanium for iPhone and Android. I created a button and a label and textfield. It looks good in iPhone but is scattered in Android.

I think I have to adjust the each of the control's position. But this would be a big overhead.

Is there any alternative mechanism there by which we can have controls correctly placed both in iphone and Android?

Comment: can you post your code? Not clear what the problem is based on your description

Comment: Just a tiny tip :) Always write sizes in %. If you do, the objects might scale, but it will always be the same size wherever you run the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [the guide for Designing the User Interface](http://guides.appcelerator.com/en/ui_design.html). With each new version of Titanium Mobile, the platform becomes more consistent between the various supported platforms. You really should not need to maintain separate codebases.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't go for same look and feel. iOS and Android are totally different OS. In Titanium you don't have many controls which are available for iOS.

Let the look and feel be different for Android, don't make it iPhonish.

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Designing+the+User+Interface

Though their docs are not maintained properly. I would suggest you to use some cool graphics which can enhance the look and feel of Application.

**I created a button and a label and textfield. It looks good in iPhone but is scattered in Android.**

It should not be, post your code. The look and feel might be different, but it should not be scattered.